# How to access email contacts from iphone appliaction programatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, abaddressbook

Hi I want to retrieve all email contacts from user email i.e gmail or yahoo or any mail from my iphone app,
Is it possible, give solution to me,
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Objective C API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)

Use this as a starting point, you can also grab their contacts with:

[Apple Contact Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)